# Foreach loop and multi array echo

Tags: php, session, web

I am having some difficulty echo'ing an multidimensional array.

Here is the array dump:

```
$_SESSION['cart']: Array
(
    [SW] => Array
        (
            [mID] => SW
            [mday] => Mon
            [mtime] => 9:00pm
            [seat] => Array
                (
                    [sa] => 8
                    [sp] => 5
                    [sc] => 2
                    [b2] => 3
                )

            [price] => $200.00
        )
)
```

and here is my echo loop:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
    <section>
        <?php foreach ($booking as $key => $value) { ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                    <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
         <?php } ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

I keep hitting an error when the loop gets to [seat].

How can I have it loop through the nested array?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need to loop seat index as well.

Comment: check if $value is an array and loop it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo an array. `echo` requires a string.

Just loop again if the value is an array.

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
    <section>
        <?php foreach ($booking as $key => $value) { ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php if(is_array($value)) {
                        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                             echo $k." > ".$v."<br/>";
                        }
                    } else { ?>
                        <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                        <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
         <?php } ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
    <section>
        <?php foreach ($booking as $bookingValue) { ?>
            <ul>
                <li>

                <?php if(is_array($bookingValue)) {
                    foreach ($bookingValue as $key => $value) { ?>
                        <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                        <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?>
                    <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                    <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                <?php } ?>

                </li>
            </ul>
         <?php } ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that echo's each item of an array, even if it contains other arrays. You need to check if `$value` is an array.

```
function echoArrayValues($array) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
       echoArrayValues($value);
       continue; 
    }
    echo $value.'<br>';
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
        <section>
            <?php foreach ($booking as $key => $value) { ?>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <?php if( $key == 'seat' ) { 
                         foreach($value as $seat_key => $seat_value) { 

                         }
                         } else { ?>
                        <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                        <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                        }?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             <?php } ?>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk_recursive($_SESSION['cart'], function($value, $key) { echo $key . ' ' . $value . PHP_EOL; })
```

output:

```
mID SW
mday Mon
mtime 9:00pm
sa 8
sp 5
sc 2
b2 3
price $200.00
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
<section>
    <?php foreach ($booking as $key => $value) { ?>
         <ul>
            <li>
                <?php if(is_array($value)) {
                    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                         echo $k." : ".$v."<br/>";
                    }
                } else { ?>
                    <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
                    <span><?php echo $value?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
     <?php } ?>
</section>
```

**output**

```
mID: SW
mday: Mon
mtime: 9:00pm
sa : 8
sp : 5
sc : 2
b2 : 3
price: $200.00
```

Comment: Did you just copy my exact answer?

Comment: @Drudge Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: @Smeckop if you think this answer is useful, then please upvote it so that it can be useful to others in the future .